# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single,compatible version of org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Unable to start my application because of the following error due to incompatible dependency versions. Please provide details on what versions should be used

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:125)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

The method's class, org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.5/spring-boot-2.4.5.jar!/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder: file:/C:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.5/spring-boot-2.4.5.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder

Following are the dependencies defined pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>employee-producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employee-producer</name>
    <description>employee-producer</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Camden is very old and unsupported. The version of spring cloud that is compatible with boot 2.4.x is 2020.0.2